# How to get css property from class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i get the 'color' property from test class but should not use .addClass and .css function.

```
.test {
  color: red;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

I need to add color property for other class.something like following

```
<div class="getproperty"></div>
```

How can i get only color property from test class to use getproperty class.

### Update :

I want to get the color property that is for the `class:test` and to use the obtained color to another class named as `getproperty`.

How can i do this in jquery ?

Comment: Why is _should not use .addClass and .css function._ restriction, ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the color from the class:

```
var color = $(".test").css("color");
$(".getproperty").css("color", color);
```

Comment: its return undefined

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9kd4uosw/ check this

Comment: It returns undefined, because it cannot find any element with class test. Here is the updated jsfiddle which returns the color. However it is in rgb format. http://jsfiddle.net/9kd4uosw/1/

Comment: You must have a html element with class test

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery you could do something like this:

```
var color = $("<i>", {class: "test"}).css("color");
$(".getproperty").css("color", color);
```

This doesn't require you have an element with the class *test* in the page

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. FF 109 and Chromium 111 return empty style values for detached elements.